# Editing MP3 Tag in Music

Tags: music

I am trying to edit MP3 tag data in Music.  I get into the edit screen, edit the info.  I click "Save" and.... nothing.  The edit isn't saved.  I have tried on multiple files and it doesn't work on any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the problem has been reported on the application's github and is not resolved yet

[Issue 156](https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/156)

[Issue 451](https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/451)

I propose to use another TAG MP3 editor like `Easy Tag` for the moment and follow this issue on the Github project

```
$ sudo apt install easytag
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestion.  I can wait for it to be fixed.

Comment: I can recommend you to try EasyTag also. Like the name says it is really easy editing tags using it.

Comment: Thanks,
I looked at the tickets 156, 451.  It looks like this bug was reported almost 3 YEARS AGO!